# Can we serialize xml with namespace using protocol buffer?

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, xmlserializer

I had created Proto file for below sample xml and i am able to serialize it.

XML  `<Employee><name>abc</name><id>123</id><email>a</email></Employee>`

Proto

```
package com.example;

option java_package = "com.example";
option java_outer_classname = "EmployeeProtoClass";

message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

But my question is if my XML has namespace like below then how what will proto file for it ? i have created like below but i am getting error(missing field name) while conversion.

XML with namespace (EmployeeIN.xml)

```
<in:Employee xmlns:in="http://employee.in.com">
    <in:name>abc</in:name>
    <in:id>123</in:id>
    <in:email>a</in:email>
</in:Employee>
```

Proto file for EmployeeIn.xml

```
package com.example;

option java_package = "com.example";
option java_outer_classname = "EmployeeINProtoClass";

message Person {
  required string in:name = 1;
  required int32 in:id = 2;
  optional string in:email = 3;
}
```

Can anyone suggest how can we serialize it using protocol buffer ?

Comment: Your XML with a namespace defined is incorrect because the namespace itself is not properly declared if you use `xmlns` only, it will declare the *default namespace* corresponding to XML tags without any prefixes, here your namespace is `in` so it should be declared as `xmlns:in` thus it should be `xmlns:in="http://employee.in.com"`

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas for your comment.. it was just example xml with namespace. my actual question is how to serialize xml which has namespace using protocol buffer ? Is Protocol buffer support serialization of xml with namespace ?

Comment: You should include the code you are using for serialization.

Comment: if i'm not wrong then there is a serialization problem using protocol buffer.am i right?

Comment: @Jayesh , Yes it is serialization problem. If XML has namespace then we are not able to serialization using protocol buffer.